# Ubuntu 20.10 update from 20.04 will only boot from recovery using llvmpipe for graphics

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-prime, 20.10

Tried to perform an update from 20.04 LTS to 20.10. All was going well until the final reboot "into" 20.10, and my computer fails to get to the desktop when booting normally. It flashes between a purple screen and a black screen and never loads the gnome desktop. It then seems to basically hang.

Naturally I then tried recovery mode from grub, and weirdly, everything boots when I go in via this route, choosing "resume". However there's still some graphical anomalies during boot, (dialogue box appears with a basic theme on the UEFI background, and then disappears), and I noticed that in - Settings - About, it's listing llvmpipe as the graphics, rather than the Intel iGPU when I go in this route. Weirdly, it also offers to (and defaults to) boot using the 5.8.0.26 kernel (which I didn't manually install) above the listing for 5.8.0.25 (which is what I believe 20.10 ships with.

My box is an HP ex-chromebox (Haswell Celeron 2995U. 1.4GHz) which ubuntu has breathed new life into even if it's a rather weak machine. Thought I'd get used to Ubuntu on something I already had first even if it is weak! Ubuntu opens up so much more than it could originally do so I'd like to get it back, especially as it was really impressive so far.

I have used a discrete GPU on this box though an rather hacky EGPU connected to the WiFi pci-express port (an Nvidia GTX 960) but I usually use the iGPU unless it needs the extra oomph for something - what I *think* happened during the update, is that the update disabled the proprietary Nvidia drivers and the Nvidia dGPU/iGPU switching, and this has messed up the X.org server settings meaning it doesn't know what to do for graphics when it boots. Recovery works by switching to the lowest form of compatible graphics modes. Yes I wish I had not made life hard for myself.

I thought purging the Nvidia drivers would fix it, but now I've far enough down this rabbit hole that I'm lost. I started trying sudo X -configure and get an error:

`FATAL: Module fbcon not found in directory`

I don't know enough about X.org.conf to have a clue what to edit in there.

I then thought I'd try a repair install from an Ubuntu live-USB, and run into a mount point error. At this point I'm ready to give up, but I'd really rather not have to start over. I figure the other thing worth trying is to reinstall the nvidia drivers and see if I can undo what I've done that way, but I thought I should ask before I cause any more damage!

I do thankfully have a backup of my home directory if I have to resort to that, but any better ideas as to how I can reset this mess without basically wiping and starting again?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not an answer, but I have no reputation to comment. I have experiencing the same issue, so I hope to bring some clues to others who can help.

I have the same chipset Haswell Celeron 2995U 1.4GHz with internal Intel graphic card.

I did upgrade from Kubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 yesterday 08 November

I get freeze(w/o cursor) and black screen on start up with 5.8.0.26 kernel, and as you say using recovery mode from grub allow me to load the desktop but it's slow and buggy and the graphic proccessor is through livmpipe. So I'm using the older kernel from 20.04 version 5.4.0.52 and it's working perfect like before upgrade and uses Mesa graphic driver.

These are crashes after install:

```
$ ls -al /var/crash

total 3052
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie    4096 nov  8 20:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root        4096 may 31 15:03 ..
-rw-r-----  1 user whoopsie  641519 nov  8 13:43 _usr_bin_kglobalaccel5.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root whoopsie 1233588 nov  8 20:11 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_libexec_xdg-desktop-portal-kde.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 user whoopsie 1235803 nov  8 13:46 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_libexec_xdg-desktop-portal-kde.1000.crash
```